# Creating a gem from a Capistrano task

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, capistrano

I have a capistrano task I am trying to make into a gem so I can use it in multiple projects. The repository for this gem is located here:

https://github.com/FoamFactory/capistrano-monorepo-assets/tree/jwir3/initial-commit

I essentially used https://github.com/sheharyarn/capistrano-rake as a basis for creating my gem.

I've tested the actual rake script, but I'm actually not importing it into the project right now. Instead, I'm trying to get it to actually import the gem successfully. When I add the gem to my Gemfile as such:

```
  gem 'capistrano-monorepoassets','0.0.6', path: "~/Source/capistrano-monorepo-assets/pkg"
```

Run `bundle install`, then attempt to import it using the following in my `Capfile`:

```
require 'capistrano/monorepoassets'
```

I get an error when I run `cap --tasks --trace`:

```
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/monorepoassets
/home/scottj/Source/foamfactory/designsystem/Capfile:37:in `require'
/home/scottj/Source/foamfactory/designsystem/Capfile:37:in `<top (required)>'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:14:in `run'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/scottj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>
```

I can't seem to get it to load the module using `require`, which is where I'm stuck. Can someone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Maybe you should rename gem's base dir from `capistrano-monorepo-assets` to `capistrano-monorepoassets`

Comment: @LyzardKyng Yes, I actually did this but haven't pushed it to the github repo yet. My apologies for the stale repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this actually was happening because I didn't understand that `bundle install` doesn't support installing local gems by specifying the path in the Gemfile. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673269/loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-for-local-gem) actually covers the problem, and, more specifically, the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15690307/281460) solved it for me.